# What would it mean when a variable is highly correlated with intercept in proc logistic in SAS?

Tags: statistics, sas, regression

I found from one of my proc logistic report that a certain variable is highly correlated with the intercept. How can I interpret it? What should I change to amend this correlation?

EDIT: Try to ask this question in a more theroetical point of view. In estimate correlation analysis output from most logistic regression package, what does it mean if you see the intercept estimate is highly correlated with a certain variable? How would you deal with such a situation? Hopefully this is a clearer way of asking the question. Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: I think you should abstract the problem even further :P

Comment: Thank you Chris, see whether the edited version helps or not :)

Comment: Do you mean that the intercept is significant in your model? I don't have my stats books on hand, but I understand a significant intercept is meaningful depending on the situation. If the independent variables are zero does the value of the intercept give a meaningful value to the dependent? This is a pure stats question, so perhaps you might get a better response here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Murray, to your question, the intercept and all other independent variables are significant according to wald chi-squared test(although it is not very reliable). My problem is all coefficients are significant and the intercept coefficient estimate is correlated with one independent coefficient estimate. But you raise a side question which I am keen to know more: if the independent variable coefficient estimate is NOT significant, shall I trust the correlation analysis of that variable or not? This is just a side question and has not direct relation to my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A positive correlation between the coefficient of the intercept and covariate means that  the bulk of your covariate values are negative (or vice versa: negative correlation will be seen with positive values).

This is not restricted to logistic regression, and might be easier to see with linear regression. Think of the scatterplot of your values as a blob to the right of the y-axis, and draw the best fitting linear regression line. Now increase both its y-intercept and slope a bit: if the "blob" is far enough, the line will completely miss it. So you can't move both parameters in the same direction while getting a reasonably fitting line. In other words the estimates are negatively correlated.

In practice, this is not a big deal. It is true that the estimate of the intercept will have a high variability, but that is not surprising if the bulk of your data is away from 0. Often x=0 is not meaningful, so you don't even care about the intercept. If you just can't bear to see those large correlations, just center your x variable. The y-axis will move to the middle of your data, and the correlation will magically vanish. Of course, the meaning of the intercept changes as well, but that is often desirable.

Comment: Good point. Maybe that particular variable's value variance is not big and a big far from y axis. I will take a look. But the explanation is really good. I am satisfied. Thank you.